# css style don't apply inside TextView for <ul> and <ol> in iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, textview, padding

I'm showing HTML data inside TextView, padding space for `<ul>` or `<ol>` is more than required but I can't adjust padding/margin using CSS (I would prefer to do using CSS) from HTML side, any suggestion how to achieve it?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      font-size: 14px;
      font-family: -apple-system, Arial, sans-serif;
      color: black;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      padding-bottom: 0px;
      line-height: 20px;
    }
    
    ul,
    ol {
      padding-left: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Professionals are often vastly more comfortable solving analytical, convergent problems than those requiring more divergent thinking. In this article, Olivier Leclerc and Mihnea Moldoveanu share some strategies for stimulating truly novel thinking.
    They introduce five "flexons," which can be thought of as "languages" for shaping problems that help you bring diverse perspectives to problem solving:</p>

  <ul type="disc">
    <li>Networks</li>
    <li>Evolutionary</li>
  </ul>


  <ol>
    <li>Decision-agent</li>
    <li>System dynamics</li>
    <li>Information-processing :
      <ol>
        <li>Decision-agent</li>
        <li>System dynamics</li>
        <li>Information-processing</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>


  <ul type="disc">
    <li>Networks :
      <ul>
        <li type="circle">Decision-agent</li>
        <li type="circle">System dynamics</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

This is HTML, `ul,ol {padding-left:10px;}` of CSS doesn't apply.

Function to converting HTML String to AttributeText

```
 extension NSAttributedString {
    convenience public init?(styled: String, textAlignment: NSTextAlignment = .center, color: UIColor = .black) {
        guard let data = styled.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode) else {
            return nil
        }
        do {
            let string = try NSMutableAttributedString(data: data,
                                                       options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)
            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.alignment = textAlignment

            string.addAttributes(
                [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: color],
                range: NSMakeRange(0, string.length)
            )

            self.init(attributedString: string.removingTrailingNewLine)
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }

    var removingTrailingNewLine: NSAttributedString {
        if string.hasSuffix("\n") {
            return attributedSubstring(from: NSRange(location:0, length: length - 1))
        }
        return self
    }
}
```

Image shows padding is a bit more than it should be, but can't adjust it. [image: Image showing the end result]

Comment: can you add some of your code please. Thank you

Comment: @Adam added code and screen shot as well.

Comment: so you want the `ul` and `ol` look like the screenshot you added?

Comment: This is how it's looking right now, I want the left margin should be less than it's showing right now.

Comment: oh just do `padding-left: 0` and this is margin not padding just to know. so make `margin-left: 10px` or zero.

Comment: @Adam Already tried that, the problem is that it doesn't apply inside TextView, it looks good on the online editor but inside iOS device & TextView it stays the same. `border` isn't supported by TextView.

Answer (score 0):

There's already a computed padding and margin value for the `ol` and `ul` and what you're looking at is the margin, so change the margin-left to zero or less then the original value.

Check this code:

```css
  ul,
ol {
  border: 1px solid red; /* for display only*/
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 50px;/* change this value and see how it works */
}
```

```html
<p>Professionals are often vastly more comfortable solving analytical, convergent problems than those requiring more divergent thinking. In this article, Olivier Leclerc and Mihnea Moldoveanu share some strategies for stimulating truly novel thinking. They
  introduce five "flexons," which can be thought of as "languages" for shaping problems that help you bring diverse perspectives to problem solving:</p>

<ul type="disc">
  <li>Networks</li>
  <li>Evolutionary</li>
</ul>


<ol>
  <li>Decision-agent</li>
  <li>System dynamics</li>
  <li>Information-processing :
    <ol>
      <li>Decision-agent</li>
      <li>System dynamics</li>
      <li>Information-processing</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>


<ul type="disc">
  <li>Networks :
    <ul>
      <li type="circle">Decision-agent</li>
      <li type="circle">System dynamics</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Already tried that, the problem is that it doesn't apply inside TextView, it looks good on the online editor but inside iOS device & TextView it stays the same. `border` isn't supported by TextView.

Comment: in iOS ? what version and device ?

Comment: I mean inside `UITextView`, it show well on `UIWebView` & `WKWebView` but inside TextView it's not showing any borders

Comment: @Zubair were you able to fix it?. I am getting too much spacing between bullet point & actual text